# BackgroundWorker and CPU usage issues?

Tags: c#, performance, backgroundworker, cpu-usage

I want to iterate through all files in my computer and save filenames to a text file. In order to avoid UI blocking, I'm using this inside a background worker. The code below works fine. However, the CPU usage is too high. sometime it's above 60%

```
  private void filelistmanagementWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{        
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    List<string> directoryList = new List<string>();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        if (d.IsReady)
        {
            ApplyAllFiles(d.Name, ProcessFile);
        }
    }

    // iterate over all personal folders
    foreach (Environment.SpecialFolder s in  Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
    {
        string pth = Environment.GetFolderPath(s);
        ApplyAllFiles(pth, ProcessFile);
    }
}

private void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
        {
            fileAction(file);
        }
        foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
        {
            try
            {
                ApplyAllFiles(subDir, fileAction);
            }
            catch
            {
                // swallow, log, whatever
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E) {  }
}

private void ProcessFile(string path)
{    
    //MessageBox.Show("1");
    // logic       
    path = path.Replace(":","");
    path = path.Replace("\\", "/");
    // MessageBox.Show(path.Replace("\\", "/"));
    if (!path.Contains("Recycle"))
    {
        try
        {               
           File.AppendAllText("allFilesList.txt", path + "@!@");
        }
        catch (Exception Ed) { 
        //    MessageBox.Show(Ed.Message); 
        }
    }
}
```

Question : **How to reduce cpu usage. It's currently above 60%**

Comment: try not to throw/catch exceptions recursively in ApplyAllFiles

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Not within the context of the algorithm itself, anyway. You can lower the priority of the running process, and there may be a way to do that programmatically, but other than that, the OS will decide how much CPU to give a running process.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce CPU usage? It shouldn't be an issue unless it is stuck at (or near to) 100% for long periods of time in which case performance will degrade.

Comment: @XN16 actually I don't see any problem in my computer, but what if the file is run in a computer with lower configuration such as Pentium III 1 Ghz Processor. Are you sure wouldn't that be a problem ?

Comment: @ShikataGaNai You could well run into problems with a lower spec computer, but in that case the only options are lowering the processes priority (as @JoaoMendes) suggested, but that is more of an OS level consideration, not application level, or using more powerful machines. Maybe adding `Thread.Sleep()` calls in your `ApplyAllFiles` method would slow it down which would lower CPU usage, but that's just a guess!

Comment: Ok Thankyou, I'm not going to worry about this issue then. @XN16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your background process using 100% of the CPU, as long as it doesn't block anything else that needs it.

For example in Windows, when the process is using 100% CPU and you press Ctrl+Alt+Delete, that should obviously take priority. If it shows the lock screen (almost) immediately then there's no problem.

If it doesn't do anything until your process has finished then you have a big problem and that's when you need to investigate. Otherwise don't worry about it!